# I need to save the XML file using linq with xml code in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have written a simple C# code to produce a xml file and at-last save it in the pc destination where my current project exists in which i'm writing the code.But the problem is when i run the code then at the last line of code the exception is generated and shows that 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Xml.dll Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1' is denied.Below is my code to generate and save xml file:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    class Class14
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XDocument xml = new XDocument(
                                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                                new XElement("Students",
                                    new XElement("Student", new XAttribute("ID", 101),
                                        new XElement("Name", "kamal"),
                                        new XElement("Gender", "Male"),
                                        new XElement("Marks", "800")),
                                    new XElement("Student", new XAttribute("ID", 102),
                                        new XElement("Name", "Sapna"),
                                        new XElement("Gender", "Female"),
                                        new XElement("Marks", "900")),
                                    new XElement("Student", new XAttribute("ID", 103),
                                        new XElement("Name", "Raju"),
                                        new XElement("Gender", "Male"),
                                        new XElement("Marks", "870"),
                                    new XElement("Student", new XAttribute("ID", 104),
                                        new XElement("Name", "Sushant"),
                                        new XElement("Gender", "Male"),
                                        new XElement("Marks", "700"))
                                    )));
            xml.Save(@"C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is quite clear. The user under which the app is running doesn't have required access to the location. So choose another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't have access to the path, try this out.

Provide XML file name,

```
xml.Save(@"C:\sample.xml");
```

if you want to store the file in project folder, Please follow this code, add System.Windows.Forms reference in your project.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Sample.xml");
```

Comment: although that did create my xml file through your code but isn't any other way so that i can create and save the xml file directly into the my project's folder container in visual studio 2013

Comment: updated the code to save the file in project folder location.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to write to this location, your app has to run under appropriate credentials, as Administrator, for example.
Then you may play with security rights, like

```
            var dir = "test_folder";
            var fileName = Path.Combine(dir, "test.xml");

            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            string user = wi.Name;

            MessageBox.Show(user);

            DirectorySecurity dsec = Directory.GetAccessControl(dir);
            dsec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow));
            try
            {
                Directory.SetAccessControl(dir, dsec);
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, "test");
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(uae.Message);
            }
            catch (SecurityException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }
```